# LOAD_RCPP_MODULE seems not right

Tags: c++, rcpp

`LOAD_RCPP_MODULE` is defined in latest `Rcpp` as below :

```
#define LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(NAME) \
Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_##NAME() ); \
Rf_eval(__load_module_call__), R_GlobalEnv );
```

> it seems a ')' is missing for calling constructor of Shield and the ')' after `__load_module_call__` for Rf_eval should be removed.

also curious about how  this Macro should be used. only find one example in RInside like

```
R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling);
```

but it's obvious that this line of code can't be compiled .and it's actually commented out.

by the way, the workaround I got is to call the code in the macro directly to load module. say the module name is "Test", code is as below, R is an instance of RInside.

```
Shield<SEXP> __load_module_call__( Rf_lang2( GET_MODULE_SYM, _rcpp_module_boot_Test() ) );
R["Test"] = Rf_eval(__load_module_call__, R_GlobalEnv );
```

Comment: Good catch. Do you want to prepare a PR for Rcpp, and then maybe one for RInside to use it?

Comment: I am not sure how LOAD_RCPP_MODULE should be used. even if the  ')' and '(' are corrected, it still can't be called like R["bling"] = LOAD_RCPP_MODULE(bling).